Vimeo API-php-sdk
I want to list only the videos after the recipe I specified among the videos available on Vimeo using the PHP SDK.
<?php


class Fetch extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
       
        
        $client = new Vimeo($vimeoClient, $vimeoSecret, $vimeoAccess);
        
      
        
        $response = $client->request('/me/videos', [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'query' => [
                'fields' => 'uri,name,created_time',
                'sort' => 'date',
                'direction' => 'desc',
                'filter' => [
                    'created_time' => [
                        'gte' => $from_date,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        
       
        foreach ($response['body']['data'] as $video) {
            echo "Video Adı: {$video['name']} - Oluşturulma Tarihi: {$video['created_time']} - URI: {$video['uri']}<br>";
        } 
    }
   
}  

Even though I write it this way, it gives me all the videos, not just the one after the date I specified. how can i solve this problem? Is there a method I can do this? Or does vimeo not provide this service?

What is $from_date supposed to contain here? Where does it get is value from?

@CBroe I pull the value from the database, I get the date of the last data added to the database, and then I want to pull the videos added after this date in Vimeo and save them to the database
